# Remove DEP notification MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

I've just bought my first MacBook and I found out that it is enrolled in MDM/DEP. The guy I bought it from had it completely sealed up with original packaging so I never thought it would have problems with it, while I also paid almost retail price.
Anyway, I have tried different solutions posted here to remove DEP notification and I get stuck at moving files to /etc/hosts. ZSH give back "access decided" error or mounting with root returns "mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66". How can I gain access to /etc/hosts ? I have searched everywhere and for M1 Macs I couldn't find an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Any chance to get hold of the seller?

Comment: Blocked me after I made enquiries regarding the problem. I also went to the police and they said its a civil matter not a criminal one since the Mac is working. A complaint for theft should filed by the 'original' Mac owner, if there is one. So.... I'm pretty much stuck. And I've been reading the forums but I just can't get the hang of the problems I mentioned above.

Comment: None of the random procedures people have invented remove a Mac from DEP.  The Mac is enrolled through Apple Business Manager, a system at Apple, not via any process done or software installed on the machine.

Comment: If the computer is in DEP, that means that Apple has it recorded as being owned & managed by a specific business or school; the Mac may've been stolen from them.

Comment: You can contact Apple support but be prepared for absolutely **PROVING** (with a paper trail, etc.) that you are the legal/legit owner of the Mac. They are the only one that can break that lock.

Comment: Thank for your inputs. I have also tried to contact the supposed owner of the device but I only have an email address and they are pretty much ignoring me. Such a shame ...

Comment: Might be helpful to get legal advice (from a laywer, not from the police). Somebody sold you a not fully functional product (also it may be stolen), there might be legal options.